# Is it safe to use double for scientific constants in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-accuracy

I want to do some calculations in C++ using several scientific constants like,

1. effective mass of electron(m) 9.109e-31 kg
2. charge of electron 1.602e-19 C
3. Boltzman constant(k) 1.38×10−23
4. Time 8.92e-13

And I have calculations like, sqrt((2kT)/m)

Is it safe to use double for these constants and for results?

Comment: Depends on the acceptable margin of error in your calculations.

Comment: What do you mean "safe" in this context?, What is your concern?

Comment: And which kind of calculation you are doing. For instance, doubles (and floats) are more subject to error problems if you are doing difference of 2 very close numbers

Comment: You should read about the [Condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of a problem

Comment: There's a famous article: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the particular example you gave (constants **and** calculations) : **YES**

You didn't define 'safe' in your problem. I will assume that **you want to keep the same number of correct significant digits**.

- doubles are correct to 15 significant digits
- you have constants that have 4 significant digits
- the operations involves use multiplication, division, and one square root
- it doesn't seem that your results are going to the 'edge' cases of *doubles* (for very small or large exponent value, where mantissa loses precision)

In this particular order, the result would be correct to 4 significant digits.

---

**In the general case, however, you have to be careful**. (probably not, and this depend on your definition of 'safe' of course).

This is a large and complicated subject. In particular, your result might not be correct to the same number of significant digits if you have :

- a lot more operations,
- if you have substractions of numbers close to each other
- other problematic operations

Obligatory reading : [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

See the good answer of [@Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47545851/479251) for other references.

Also, for complex calculations, it is relevant to have some notion of the [Condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of a problem.

Comment: And the correct number for doubles is 15 significant *decimal* digits *in integer values*. It becomes meaningless to discuss when fractions are involved.

Comment: Consider 1/128.  It is 0.0078125 to six decimal places, but in a floating-point number it is only one significant fractional bit. The reverse can also apply.

Answer (score 7):

**floating point arithmetic and accuracy is a very tricky subject.** Read absolutely the [floating-point-gui.de](http://floating-point-gui.de/) site.

Errors of many floating point operations can accumulate to the point of giving meaningless results. Several catastrophic events (loss of life, billions of dollars crashes) happened because of this. More will happen in  the future.

There are some static [source analyzers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_analysis) dedicated to detect them, for example [Fluctuat](http://www.di.ens.fr/~cousot/projects/DAEDALUS/synthetic_summary/CEA/Fluctuat/index.html) (by my CEA colleagues, several now at Ecole Polytechnique, Palaiseau, France) and others. But [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) applies so that static analysis problem is unsolvable in general.

<sup>(but static analysis of floating point accuracy could sometimes *practically* work on some *small* programs of a few thousand lines, and do not scale well to large programs)</sup>

There are also some programs instrumenting calculations, for example [CADNA](http://www-pequan.lip6.fr/cadna//) from LIP6 in Paris, France.

<sup>(but instrumention may give a huge over-approximation of the error)</sup>

You could design your numerical algorithms to be less sensitive to floating point errors. This is very difficult (and you'll need [years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) of work to acquire the relevant skills and expertise).

<sup>(you need both numerical, mathematical, and computer science skills, PhD-level)</sup>

You could also use [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), or extended precision one (e.g. 128 bit floats or [quad-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format)). This slows down the computations.

An important consideration is how much effort (time and money) you can allocate to hunt floating point errors, and how much do they matter to your particular problem. But there is [*No Silver Bullet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet), and the question of floating point accurary remains a very difficult issue (you could work your entire life on it).

<sup>PS. I am *not* a floating point expert. I just happen to know some.</sup>

Answer (score -2):

If you need a yes or no answer, **No**.